# R - interaction with only one factor level in regression

Tags: r, lm

In a regression model is it possible to include an interaction with only one dummy variable of a factor? For example, suppose I have:

```
x: numerical vector of 3 variables (1,2 and 3)
y: response variable
z: numerical vector
```

Is it possible to build a model like:

```
y ~ factor(x) + factor(x) : z
```

but only include the interaction with one level of `X`?    I realize that I could create a separate dummy variable for each level of `x`, but I would like to simplify things if possible.

Really appreciate any input!!

Comment: Why would you want to do this? This seems nonsensical at first blush.

Comment: Perhaps it is nonsensical. I am still in the learning phase, but I couldn't seem to find any answers to my immediate issue anywhere. 

To be more clear, I have a cox proportional hazards model where I suspect only one of my categorical variables interacts with time. If I include that as a dummy variable it complicates the survfit function as the "newdata" must include the dummy variable.

Comment: Why not reshape the data a bit and create a new data.frame only including the interactions needed?

Comment: Its more a question of simplicity. My understanding is that R regresses each category in a factor against the response variable as a dummy variable - hence coefficients are estimated for each category. There must be some simple way to tell R to only regress one of the dummy variables within a factor against the response ?

Comment: It may well be that only 1 group (out of 3) changes over time, but little is lost by including all 3 factors in the interaction. One of your factors will be held out as a reference group against which the others will be compared. You use 2 degrees of freedom to estimate the interaction, if you do it the way you want, you'll use 1. IE, you save only 1 df; even if this made sense, it can hardly be worth the trouble.

Comment: Right! Definitely. Unfortunately my case is unique right now in that when all three interactions are tested I run into this problem outlined by someone here: 

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-September/174201.html

 - the model won't converge. However, if I do things in the long way and only include 1 interaction - I find it will converge just fine. Now I want to clean up my syntax and make it easier for further investigations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One key point you're missing is that when you see a significant effect for something like `x2:z`, that doesn't mean that `x` interacts with `z` when `x == 2`, it means that *the difference between `x == 2` and `x == 1`* (or whatever your reference level is) interacts with z. It's not a level of `x` that is interacting with `z`, it's one of the contrasts that has been set for `x`.

So for a 3 level factor with default treatment contrasts:

```
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:3, 10, TRUE), y = rnorm(10), z = rnorm(10))
df$x <- factor(df$x)
contrasts(df$x)
  2 3
1 0 0
2 1 0
3 0 1
```

if you really think that only the first contrast is important, you can create a new variable that compares `x == 2` to `x == 1`, and ignores `x == 3`:

```
df$x_1vs2 <- NA
df$x_1vs2[df$x == 1] <- 0
df$x_1vs2[df$x == 2] <- 1
df$x_1vs2[df$x == 3] <- NA
```

And then run your regression using that:

```
lm(y ~ x_1vs2 + x_1vs2:z)
```

Comment: Thanks! That explains a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If `x` is already coded as a factor in your data, something like

```
y ~ x + I(x=='some_level'):z
```

Or if `x` is of numeric type in your data frame, then

```
y ~ as.factor(x) + I(as.factor(x)=='some_level'):z
```

Or to only model some subset of the data try:

```
lm(y ~ as.factor(x) + as.factor(x):z, data = subset(df, x=='some_level'))
```

Comment: This solution seems to have the same issue as Matthew Lundberg's

Comment: If you only want to analyze the subset of data that includes x=='some_level', then subset your data... added to my answer above

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help. Unfortunately I am not trying to model just a subset. See comments under main question for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
X <- data.frame(x = sample(1:3, 10, TRUE), y = rnorm(10), z = rnorm(10))
lm(y ~ factor(x) + factor(x):z, data=X)
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: In this case each level in factor(x) will interact with z if my understanding is correct. I'm looking for a way to just have an interaction of the first level of factor(x) with z.  (i.e. end up with only 1 interaction coefficient)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may be what you need:

```
y~factor(x)+factor(x=='SomeLevel'):z
```

Comment: This is definitely the concept I am looking for. However, this breaks down x into TRUE and FALSE and tests both as an interaction with z

the result is a model with x=somelevel:z x!=somelevel:z

I'm trying to include just x=somelevel:z

Comment: What to do with the rest?  Perhaps you need to partition the data, and only model where x==somelevel?

Comment: Results in `fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient`